# SailsJS / Waterline ORM : Update multiple entries using only one query

Tags: javascript, orm, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm currently using SailsJS framework, and i'm trying to update an array of elements using only one query in my MongoDB database.

Here is what I'm doing but records are not updated..

**Incoming JSON:**

```
{
  "cars": [
    {
      "id": "5cb5cbd5c395a01b4c9d86da",
      "latitude": "-5",
      "longitude": "551"
    },
    {
      "id": "5cb5cbd7c395a01b4c9d86db",
      "latitude": "-4",
      "longitude": "4421",
    }
  ]
}
```

**Controller:**

```
async setLocationOfCars(req, res) {

    try {

        sails.log.info(controllerName + "::" + req.options.action + "() - called");

        const carsLocationArray = req.body.cars;

        let response = CarService.setLocationOfCars(carsLocationArray);
        switch (response.status) {
            case constants.RESOURCE_SUCCESSFULLY_UPDATED :
                return HttpResponseService.json(200, res, constants.RESOURCE_SUCCESSFULLY_UPDATED, response.data);
            default:
                return HttpResponseService.internalServerError(res, response);
        }

    } catch(err) {
        return HttpResponseService.internalServerError(res, err);
    }

}
```

**Service:**

```
async setLocationOfCars(cars) {

    try {

        const arrayOfIdsUpdated = [];
        _.forEach(cars, async function(car){

            let attributesToUpdate = {};
            if (car.hasOwnProperty("latitude")) {
                attributesToUpdate.latitude = car.latitude;
            }
            if (car.hasOwnProperty("longitude")) {
                attributesToUpdate.longitude = car.longitude;
            }

            await Car.updateOne({
                id: car.id
            }).set(attributesToUpdate);

            arrayOfIdsUpdated.push(gateway.id)

        });

        return {
            status: constants.RESOURCE_SUCCESSFULLY_UPDATED,
            data  : arrayOfIdsUpdated
        };

    } catch (err) {
        return {
            status : constants.DATABASE_ERROR,
            name   : err.name ? err.name      : "",
            message: err.message ? err.message: "",
            stack  : err.stack ? err.stack    : "",
            code   : err.code ? err.code      : "",
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In your Controller

Make sure you are `await`ing the response from your service.

```js
let response = await CarService.setLocationOfCars(carsLocationArray);
```

#### In your "Service"

I'd probably replace `_.forEach` with a regular `for` loop. In your case something like the following, ensuring that `gateway.id` is actually defined & the value you want to return to the calling code (there's no reference to `gateway` in your question).

```js
for (let car of cars) {
  let attributesToUpdate = {};
  if (car.hasOwnProperty("latitude")) {
    attributesToUpdate.latitude = car.latitude;
  }
  if (car.hasOwnProperty("longitude")) {
    attributesToUpdate.longitude = car.longitude;
  }

  await Car.updateOne({
    id: car.id
  }).set(attributesToUpdate);


  // Where does gateway.id come from?
  arrayOfIdsUpdated.push(gateway.id)
}
```

That said, this will perform `cars.length` amount of database queries, not "using only one query".

#### But why not _.forEach?

Using an `async` callback inside forEach like doesn't look like it will do what you probably want it to do. It's likely that your `arrayOfIdsUpdated` will be returned to your controller code empty, *before* any of the calls to `updateOne` run.

Take this for example:

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

function doNothing() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 0)
  });
}

var foos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
_.forEach(foos, async (foo) => {
  await doNothing();
  console.log(`Finished #${foo}`);
});


console.log('Done!')
```

Running it gives the output

```
Done!
Finished #1
Finished #2
Finished #3
Finished #4
Finished #5
Finished #6
```

Note how the "Done!" gets logged to the console before the stuff `await`ing a response in the forEach callback.